# JUnit not working on IntelliJ Android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, junit

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

I have done everything like in this step by step tutorial and still when I try to write the line

```
import org.junit.*;
```

The "junit" part is lighten red and the error message is "cannot resolve symbol "junit"".

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you are following seems to be written for command line usage. (Download jar, set classpath etc). So the same wouldn't work in IntelliJ.
IDEs actually make these a lot easier.

To solve your current dilemma, try this. Place the cursor on the red 'junit' (which is basically a broken import) and choose "Add Junit4 to classpath". This will add the necessary junit jars that IDEA ships with to your classpath.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open up your build.gradle and make sure JUnit is there

```
dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  // other dependencies...
}
```

And for a better link for Android-specifics, read [Getting Started with Testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html) from the Android docs.